# Assigning values to Others keyword in Ada

Tags: ada

I have a doubt in using ADA.

```
others := (others := -1)
```

Is this statement a valid one. If it is invalid why is it invalid?

Comment: What do you think it might mean? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
others := (others := -1)
```

No, that's not valid.  It's a syntax error (which you could have found out by compiling it).

It's difficult to tell what it's supposed to be, but this is valid:

```
procedure Foo is
    A: array(1 .. 10) of Integer;
begin
    A := ( others => 42 );    
end Foo;
```

And so is this:

```
procedure Foo is
    A2: array(1 .. 10, 1 .. 10) of Integer;
begin
    A2 := ( others => ( others => 42 ) );
end Foo;
```

The second seems closest to what you wrote, assuming both occurrences of `others` are meant to be the keyword.  The main errors in your code snippet are that (a) you need to use `=>` rather than `:=`, and (b) even with that change, the snippet is not valid by itself; it needs context.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `others` is a reserved Ada keyword, so you cannot use it as variable name. `others' keyword defines the remaining options in a list of options.

Assume that's an unintended mistake, and what you meant to do is something like:

```
other := (other := -1)
```

This won't work, the assignment operator does not return a value, so `other := -1` is not a value thus cannot be assigned.

On the other hand though, something like the following is valid given the type of other is boolean:

```
other := (other = false);
```

In this case, the comparison operator `=` returns a boolean value, which is then assigned to variable other.